# elm-test Expect print message on failure?

Tags: elm

Most unit test frameworks support having a string in the assertion that gets printed out when the assertion fails. So far I don't see that ability in elm-test?(!)

Answer (score 0):

The [`onFail`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/elm-test/latest/Expect#onFail) function gives the ability to give a custom failure message for any of the other expectations. From the docs:

```
"something"
    |> Expect.equal "something else"
    |> Expect.onFail "thought those two strings would be the same"
```